# How would I go about assigning a different colour for each string?

Tags: javascript, string, colors

I need to change the colours of each string.

```
  $(".typedsmartbackspace").typed({
         strings: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Hamster'],
         typeSpeed: 80,
         backSpeed: 20,
         startDelay: 1000,
         backDelay: 300,
         loop: true,
         showCursor: true,
  });
```

I'd like `['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Hamster']`, to render in their own colours. Is there any way of doing this inline with the code?

Comment: Depends if that plugin supports styling elements or not without having to be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap with a `span` and add style to the span(color) tag since it accepts HTML content.

```js
$(".typedsmartbackspace").typed({
  strings: ['<span style="color:red">Dog</span>', '<span style="color:green">Cat</span>', '<span style="color:yellow">Mouse</span>', '<span style="color:blue">Hamster</span>'],
  typeSpeed: 80,
  backSpeed: 20,
  startDelay: 1000,
  backDelay: 300,
  loop: true,
  showCursor: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>

<div class="typedsmartbackspace"></div>
```